# Setting up Virtual Environment for Python on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I'm having issues with setting up the virtual environment on my Windows 10 computer. I suspect that it might have to do with the GNU C compiler I have installed but I'm not sure.

So first I did: `python3 -m venv env`
This created the following folders:

- `bin` (includes the activate file — does not have the '`.bat`' extension — and the `active.ps1` file)
- include(`empty`)
- `lib` (`pip`, `setuptools`, etc)
  and the folder
- `pyvenv.cfg`

In `pyvenv.cfg`:

```
home = C:\msys64\mingw64\bin #Not the path to my python interpreter, it's my c compiler
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.9.7
```

So naturally, I looked at several tutorials to activate venv and when I try their method for windows computers in the cmd prompt it says that the path or command does not exist.

Furthermore, in the `active` file in the first line of the code, it says it must be used from bash.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had almost the same problem, few mounths ago. For me problem was that Python compiler was not in PATH. Try checking if Python is in environment variables - System ***(Control Panel)>> Advanced system settings>> Environment Variables***

Comment: Thank You So Much!!! Saved me hours of researching for it myself. For me it was actually that the default system python interpreter was selected as the one inside my MinGW directory(c compiler. python interpreter is for Linux) and not my usual interpreter that I separately installed for windows. So after I fixed that it worked like a charm! Once again thank you!